# Nodejs Proxy saliendo con conexion desde otro equipo

Tags: jquery, nodejs, proxy, redes, https

Tengo un script en `NodeJS` que se conecta a una API HTTPS, pero el servidor donde se encuentra dicho script se encuentra detrás de un proxy que no permite salida por HTTPS. Mi consulta es: ¿Cómo puedo hacer un script para que utiliza la salida de internet de otro equipo que su proxy si permite conexión HTTPS. Quiero decir que este mismo script, si funciona en un server con salida a internet y se conecta a la API HTTPS. Entonces, desde el servidor que no tiene salida HTTPS, quiero usar el internet del servidor que si permite salida HTTPS, los cuales los dos servidores se encuentran dentro de la red LAN.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si se configura un proxy HTTP en el equipo que tiene permisos para conexiones HTTPS, es relativamente sencillo conectarse a través de ese equipo:

```
var http = require('http');

http.get ({
    host: '192.168.1.100', //IP del equipo donde configuraste el proxy
    port: 8080,
    path: 'https://www.url.com/de/API'
}, function (rta) {
    // Procesar la respuesta
    console.log (rta);
});
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta. Quizas no me exprese bien. Usted me esta dando un ejemplo de como conectarme al proxy server con un script en node (un cliente en node seria). yo necesito saber como escribir ese serverproxy en nodejs, cual seria el codigo, como lo hago, como levanto un servidor proxy. Gracias